# JPA Crud repository query method not working

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to get a list of users by username, with enabled status and has phone number. I managed to get it working till I add the phone number parameter.

here is my code:

```
//crud repo
List<Users> findAllByUserNameContainsAndEnabledIsAndMobileNotNull(String userName, String  enabled);
```

```
// controller

public Set<User> searchByName(@PathVariable String username) throws Exception {
        Set<User> result = new HashSet<>();
        result.addAll(userRepository.findAllByUserNameContainsAndEnabledIsAndMobileNotNull(username, "Y"));

        return result;

    }

// user class

public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(precision = 18, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal id;
    
    @Column(name = "Enabled", columnDefinition = "char(1) default 'Y'")
    private String enabled;

    private String username;

    private String mobile;

// getters setters..
```

Comment: please post your `User` class

Comment: added my user class

Comment: is it typo? `List<Users>` - should be `User`

Comment: I have reproduced your case in new project and everything works using custom method that returns `List<User>`.

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

What is your phone number parameter called? You said it was working until that. The names have to match.

Here is all supported keywords in the method names:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Please use comments when clarifying additional points. This is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have started new project and everything works as expected, so the problem is not in method name. Here is code I've tested:

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(precision = 18, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal id;

    @Column(name = "Enabled", columnDefinition = "char(1) default 'Y'")
    private String enabled;

    private String userName;

    private String mobile;

    public User(String enabled, String userName, String mobile) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

**Repositiory**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, BigDecimal> {
    List<User> findAllByUserNameContainsAndEnabledIsAndMobileNotNull(String userName, String  enabled);
}
```

**Test**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Test
    void test_findAllByUserNameContainsAndEnabledIsAndMobileNotNull() {

        User user1 = new User("Y", "user1", "mobile");
        User user2 = new User("Y", "user2", null);
        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.save(user2);

        List<User> all = userRepository.findAllByUserNameContainsAndEnabledIsAndMobileNotNull("user", "Y");
        System.out.println("all = " + all);
    }
}
```

And only one record in the output:

> all = [User(id=1, enabled=Y, userName=user1, mobile=mobile)]